# Relation implication

Tags: derivatives

For $n \geq 0$ the following holds:

$y^{(n+2)}(0) = -n^2y^{(n)}(0)$

Given the above relation, where superscript denotes the $n$th derivative with respect to $x$ and $(0)$ means function is evaluated at point $0$. How does the fact that $y^{(0)}(0)=0$ imply that all $y^{(2k)}(0)=0$ (i.e. even power derivatives evaluate to $0$?)

EDIT: I think I got it. It is like a recursion thing.

Yeah I got it.

Answer (score 0):

If $n=2k$ then the relation gives $ y^{(2k)}(0)=(-1)^k \ n^{2k}\  y^{(0)}(0)=(-1)^k \ n^{2k}\ 0=0 $

EDIT: If you must prove the equality I've written, it's induction on $k \in \mathbb{N}$